# recovered .tex file, but text inside file is unrecognizable

Tags: errors, conversion, text, metadata

[image]I have used several programs to recover .tex files that were accidentally deleted from an external hard drive. The .tex files were recovered, but when I opened them, the text inside is completely unrecognizable. There is a sample picture below.

Does anyone recognize what this is? Is there anyway I can recover what I originally had written in the .tex file?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe an encoding problem?

Comment: @Bernard Is there a program that can fix that?

Comment: @Melvin you can open it in a [text (plain) editor](https://askubuntu.com/a/581120/16395)  (notepad++ has it, I think) and try to change encoding to the correct one, and then retry deleting the first byte of the file (In multibyte encoding, say, UTF16, loosing a byte can mess everything up).

Comment: @Rmano Okay so I opened it with Notepad and I see that I have options to change the encoding when I Save As. What do I change it to, though? I tried changing it to UTF-8, and when I opened this new file in TEXWorks, I still get a file with unrecognizable text.

Comment: What is the operating system under which it was saved before being deleted?

Comment: @Bernard It had been saved on a hard drive on a Windows 10 system before having to do a total pc restore. Then I connected this hard drive to a Mac laptop and accidentally unmounted the drive, which deleted all of the files inside.

Comment: Just in case, try to  convert it to MacOS encoding (but make a copy first). Also, I believe that TeX editors like TeXmaker or TeX studio can guess the encoding of the file, and they can convert it anyway.

Comment: Useful info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/539323/2907484

Comment: all the ? are the text-replacement character but that is almost certainly done when you pasted the fragment into this site (as it's invalid utf-8) so it's impossible to see your original code.  If you can put the file in a pastebin or similar then perhaps someone could look at it. Also if you can recognise the letters and match the original text say what you think the text should be

Comment: You have changed the image, the fragments now show /Subtype...   That is PDF not TeX, you have recovered the output not your source file there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, that is actually the source file. I can't even compile to get a PDF. I get a whole bunch of erros when I try to compile. Maybe the file is damaged and unrecoverable?

Comment: no.  the fragments of your image that are readable are PDF.